# Nuxt can render the object but not its property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm fetching a data from a directus API which returns data in an array of objects, it would render if i try putting the array or an object from it but not when i try accessing a property of the object

```
 <template>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-6 mt-6">
        <div class="flex justify-center items-center">
            <div class="flex flex-col items-stretch w-full">
            <img loading="lazy" src="@/assets/images/berita-1.png" class="aspect-[1.7] object-fit-cover object-center max-w-[580] overflow-hidden max-w-full" />
            <h3 class="text-black text-justify text-l font-bold py-4">
                <a href="#">{{ Berita[0].Title }}</a>
            </h3>
            <p class="line-clamp-2 text-justify text-black">
                Departemen Teknik Industri Fakultas Teknik Universitas Hasanuddin menggelar
                International Guest Lecturer yang dibawakan oleh Profesor yang juga sebagai 
                Head Of Laboratory Ergonomics for All Ages and Abilities dari Kyushu 
                University Prof. Satoshi Muraki, Ph.D., CPE. International Guest Lecturer 
                dilaksanakan pada Senin 9, Oktober 2023 dan dilaksanakan secara daring dan 
                luring di Gedung CSA LT 1 Fakultas Teknik Universitas Hasanuddin.
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

here is what's inside Berita (an array of object)

```
[
    {
        "id": "8f790756-54e2-43fe-8a23-5aa49277a9af",
        "sort": null,
        "user_created": "a4655746-7c37-4b7d-9739-8e0d85d6503a",
        "date_created": "2023-11-09T01:11:13.228Z",
        "Title": "Fakultas Teknik Universitas Hasanuddin Terima Kunjungan Benchmarking Universitas Halu Oleo.",
        "Slug": "fakultas-teknik-universitas-hasanuddin-terima-kunjungan-benchmarking-universitas-halu-oleo",
        "Konten": "<p>Fakultas Teknik Universitas Hasanuddin menerima kunjungan dari Universitas Halu Oleo. Kunjungan ini dilaksanakan dalam rangka Benchmarking Program Studi Magister Teknik Sipil dan Program Studi Pendidikan Profesi Insinyur. Benchmarking tersebut dilaksanakan pada Senin, 6 November 2023 di Ruang Rapat Lantai 3 Gedung CoT Fakultas Teknik Universitas Hasanuddin.&nbsp;</p>\n<p>Acara dibuka langsung Wakil Dekan Bidang Kemitraan, Riset, dan Inovasi Dr. Ir. Rustan Tarakka, ST., M.T., IPM., ASEAN,Eng. dan dihadiri oleh Kepala Program Studi Magister Teknik Sipil Dr. M. Asad Abdurrahman, S.T., M.Eng.PM., Kepala Program Studi Pendidikan Profesi Insinyur&nbsp; Dr. Eng. Ilham Bakri, ST., M.Sc., Wakil Dekan Bidang Kemahasiswaan dan Alumni Prof. Dr. Ir. Adris A. Putra. S.T., M.T dan didampingi oleh dosen dan staf Fakultas Teknik Universitas Halu Oleo.&nbsp;</p>\n<p>Dalam sambutannya, Dr. Rustan menyampaikan selamat datang kembali kepada Delegasi Universitas Halu Oleo, dan berharap semoga dengan adanya benchmarking ini kedua belah pihak bisa saling berdiskusi mengenai Pembukaan Program Studi Magister Teknik Sipil dan Program Studi Pendidikan Profesi Insinyur.&nbsp;</p>\n<p>Sedangkan Prof Adris dalam kesempatan ini menyampaikan apresiasi kepada Fakultas Teknik Universitas Hasanuddin yang telah menerima delegasi Fakultas Teknik Universitas Halu Oleo. Kunjungan ini dalam rangka pembukaan Program Studi Magister Teknik Sipil dan Program Studi Pendidikan Profesi Insinyur,sehingga membutuhkan sumber daya manusia yang sesuai dengan bidangnya. Prof Adris juga menyampaikan bahwa alasan Universitas Halu Oleo memilih Universitas Hasanuddin untuk melaksanakan Benchmarking karena melihat hampir lebih dari setengah dosen di Fakultas Teknik Universitas Halu Oleo adalah alumni dari Universitas Hasanuddin.</p>\n<p>Setelah pembukaan, Benchmarking ini dilanjutkan dengan sharing session untuk mendiskusikan dan menjelaskan bagaimana pembukaan Program Magister Teknik Sipil dan Program Studi Pendidikan Profesi Insinyur.</p>",
        "cover": "b3653d1c-201d-45bc-8b4c-000b5d09af6e"
    },
    {
        "id": "30d4a1bf-fba0-46ae-8862-2f5b5bb2d1f7",
        "sort": null,
        "user_created": "a4655746-7c37-4b7d-9739-8e0d85d6503a",
        "date_created": "2023-11-15T08:38:15.496Z",
        "Title": "Fakultas Teknik Gelar Sosialisasi Penginputan RKAT Tahun 2024",
        "Slug": "fakultas-teknik-gelar-sosialisasi-penginputan-rkat-tahun-2024",
        "Konten": "<p>Fakultas Teknik Universitas Hasanuddin laksanakan Sosialisasi Rencana Kerja dan Anggaran Tahunan Tahun 2024. Sosialisasi ini dilaksanakan pada Rabu, 8 November 2023 di Exhibition Hall Gedung CoT fakultas Teknik Universitas Hasanuddin.</p>\n<p>Sosialisasi ini dibuka langsung oleh Dekan Fakultas Teknik Universitas Hasanuddin Prof. Dr. Eng. Ir. Muhammad Isran Ramli, S.T., M.T., IPM., AER. Setelah sambutan dilanjutkan dengan acara inti yaitu Sosialisasi Penginputan RKAT yang dibawakan oleh Wakil Dekan Bidang Perencanaan, Sumber Daya, dan Alumni Dr. Eng. Ir. Muhammad Rusman, M.T. dan Dr. Ir. M. Yahya, ST., M.Eng selaku &nbsp;Direktur Perencanaan dan Pengembangan Universitas Hasanuddin.&nbsp;</p>\n<p>Setelah Presentasi Sosialisasi yang dilakukan Dr. Rusman dan Dr. Yahya, Acara ini dilanjutkan dengan penyerahan alokasi pagu tahun 2024 Kepala Departemen Se- Fakultas Teknik Universitas Hasanuddin.&nbsp;</p>",
        "cover": "7d5d334c-bbd0-44b0-8853-cf95f9fe1275"
    },
    {
        "id": "f972c425-7b5d-4376-bc39-1b17e0c75ab0",
        "sort": null,
        "user_created": "a4655746-7c37-4b7d-9739-8e0d85d6503a",
        "date_created": "2023-11-15T15:17:02.968Z",
        "Title": "Fakultas Teknik Universitas Hasanuddin Laksanakan Sosialisasi Panduan Penelitian dan Pengabdian Masyarakat Tahun 2024",
        "Slug": "fakultas-teknik-universitas-hasanuddin-laksanakan-sosialisasi-panduan-penelitian-dan-pengabdian-masyarakat-tahun-2024",
        "Konten": "<p>Memasuki akhir tahun 2023 Fakultas Teknik Universitas Hasanuddin menggelar Sosialisasi Panduan Penelitian dan Pengabdian Kepada Masyarakat Tahun 2024. Sosialisasi ini dilaksanakan Selasa, 7 November 2023 di Gedung CSA LT1, Fakultas Teknik Universitas Hasanuddin, Gowa.&nbsp;</p>\n<p>Acara ini dihadiri oleh Sekretaris Lembaga Penelitian dan Pengabdian Masyarakat Universitas Hasanuddin Ir. Suharman Hamzah, ST., MT., Ph.D(Eng)., HSE, Wakil Dekan Bidang Kemitraan, Riset, dan Inovasi Dr. Ir. Rustan Tarakka, S.T., M.T., IPM., AER, Kepala Departemen dan Dosen Di Fakultas Teknik Universitas Hasanuddin.&nbsp;</p>\n<p>Sosialisasi ini bertujuan untuk memperkenalkan panduan penelitian dan pengabdian masyarakat yang akan digunakan untuk tahun 2024 kedepan. Untuk itu sosialisasi ini menghadirkan dua pemateri yaitu Prof. Dr. Moh Ivan, Az., M.Sc., dan Prof. Dr. Ir. Jasmal Ahmari Syamsu, M.Si., IPU, AER.</p>",
        "cover": "38cb8ef9-aca8-465e-ac9d-7ef0901e6cfa"
    },
    {
        "id": "96e815b7-e2fc-4862-a414-497492aeba55",
        "sort": null,
        "user_created": "a4655746-7c37-4b7d-9739-8e0d85d6503a",
        "date_created": "2023-11-15T15:23:46.794Z",
        "Title": "Sambut Dosen UGM dan ITS, Departemen Teknik Kelautan Universitas Hasanuddin Gelar Kuliah Tamu.",
        "Slug": "sambut-dosen-ugm-dan-its-departemen-teknik-kelautan-universitas-hasanuddin-gelar-kuliah-tamu",
        "Konten": "<p>Dalam rangka Seminar Nasional Sains dan Teknologi Kelautan 2023, Departemen Teknik Kelautan Universitas Hasanuddin mengundang narasumber dari Universitas Gadjah Mada dan Institut Teknologi Sepuluh November. Hal ini juga dimanfaatkan untuk melaksanakan Guest Lecturer atau Kuliah Tamu. Kuliah Tamu ini dilaksanakan pada Kamis, 2 November 2023 di Ruang LT1 Gedung CSA Fakultas Teknik Universitas Hasanuddin, Gowa.&nbsp;</p>\n<p>Kuliah tamu ini menghadirkan dua materi, materi pertama adalah Coastal dan Marine Hazard yang dibawakan oleh Dr. Ir. Wahyudi, M.Sc. Dosen Teknik Kelautan Institut Teknologi Sepuluh November. Kemudian materi kedua yaitu Pengenalan Software SWAN dan INTERPOL yang dibawakan oleh Prof. Ir. Radianta Triatmadja, Ph.D, Dosen Teknik Sipil dan Lingkungan Universitas Gadjah Mada.</p>\n<p>Kuliah tamu ini juga dihadiri oleh Kepala Departemen Teknik Kelautan Universitas Hasanuddin Dr. Ir. Chairul Paotonan, ST., MT., Sekretaris Departemen Dr. Hasdinar Umar, S.T., M.T. Dan diikuti oleh seluruh Tendik, Dosen dan Mahasiswa Departemen Teknik Kelautan Universitas Hasanuddin</p>",
        "cover": "5fe64dc6-4627-4e3c-8abc-08cba328c64e"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are only a few cases that cause this problem, most of which are due to you:

1. `fetch` call is `Promise` so surely it is initially `undefined` and we have nothing to do with it let's use:

```js
  <a href="#">{{ Berita?.[0].Title }}</a>
```

2. A rare case is that you use `RefLike` which causes `vue` to fail to resolve reactant when this happens adding the suffix `.value` will resolve the issue:

```js
  <a href="#">{{ Berita.value?.[0].Title }}</a>
```

Comment: It didnt work, but i found something that worked for me was `<a href="#">{{ Berita[0]?.Title }}</a>`

Comment: What is RefLike? An object with value key that wasn't produced with ref()?

Comment: @EstusFlask it is something like ref which is generally something with `.value` like `ref`, `shallowRef`, `computed`, `customRef`...

Comment: These ones are actual refs and their behaviour in a template is predictable, top-level ref like Berita.value is unwrapped to Berita, snippet 2 will result in an error.

Comment: if you have a computed that returns 1 ref or a reactive that returns 1 computed or an object that has 1 ref or computed the second case will happen

Comment: https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9Uc1OAjEQfpVJL0CCEINeyEKihoMe1KjHXsgyLMVu27RT3GSz7+60G1YPhFvn++s3mVY8ODc7RRRLUYTSK0cQkKJbS6NqZz1BCx73MIXS1i4S7qCDvbc1jNg1kkaa0ppAUIcKVoNoPJ7Aap2c47v7yUSaYt6ncy4PhLXTW0KeAIrD7bptc0DXFXOeMqoMJ8HpprY71CspmJeCqWI+uMVUUODv96qaHYM1vESbvFKkHkqjf3OkuJ4US8hM4rZa25+XjJGPOD3j5QHL7wv4MTQJk+LdY0B/QikGjra+QurpzecrNvweSG4eNauvkB8YrI6pYy97jGbHtf/pctvnfAplqq+waQhNOC+ViiZll/VS8E2erqz+V3cxW2SfNJ3ofgHX46qE